# If statement does not execute statement even if true

Tags: c#

if Statment works fine on localhost, but strangely not on the production server. Always Executes the else part once hosted on the server.

```
   public ActionResult Logged_in()
    {
        try
        {
            string abc = "0";
            int m = 0;
            abc = Session["emp_code"].ToString();

            if (abc == "4035")
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Pending", "NIC_CO_OP");
            }
            else {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Comment: How are you initializing your Session on your server? It seems that abc never has 4035 on the server. Maybe the server database does not have that value and you have that on your localhost?

Comment: So you're question should obviously be "why is `abc` not `"4035"` on the production server?"

Comment: Are you sure the Session variable `emp_code` is set in production? And if so is it "4035"?

Comment: @RahulSharma yes, Im initializing it when i check if the user exists and then store it in the sesssion. And Yes, 4035 user exists on the server.

Comment: @RenéVogt yes, Correct

Comment: So, check that code @RahulHanchate

Comment: @RahulHanchate Try setting your string as: `string abc = string.empty`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Sorry wrong Rahul here. :)

Comment: @RahulHanchate `if` works. If the first branch doesn't run it's because abc doesn't contain the string `4035`. You'll have to debug your code to see what it actually contains. Perhaps the string stored in the session contains whitespace. Perhaps it's empty. Or something else. The only thing that's certain is that it doesn't contain the characters `4035`

Comment: @RahulHanchate is there any chance that `emp_code` is a string instead of a number? If it's a number you should cast the session value to an int instead of creating a string, eg `var abc = (int)Session["emp_code"]; if (abc==4035){...}`

Comment: @RahulSharma fixed

Comment: @RahulSharma Tried your method. Still no Luck

Comment: @RahulSharma string.empty worked.. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your specific case, initialize your string `abc` as:

```
string abc = string.empty
```

This will always ensure that `abc` has an empty value during initialization. Then once you get your data from your `Session`, `abc` is set accordingly.